# Поддерживает ли Яндекс браузер для андроид pwa приложения?

Tags: android, pwa, яндекс-браузер

И если поддерживает, то каким способом их можно устанавливать с помощью яндекс браузера на андроид?

Answer (score 1):

Тоже вот только что столкнулся с таким же, открываю PWA в Яндекс.Браузере на Android 8 а он сайт открывает, но не предлагает сделать иконку на рабочий стол

А если сделать ее через меню Яндекса, то это будет обычная ссылка на сайт, а не PWA

При этом через стоковый браузер телефона спокойно устанавливается